# Move files into a folder/branch?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I made a mistake and checked in a new project into the "root" of the project repository on VSTS. I meant to create a new folder -- better yet a new branch -- then check the project into the repository.

Is there a way to move the files into a folder or branch on VSTS?

BTW, I'm using TFVC on VSTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the thing you want to move in the source control explorer, then choose "Move" from the context menu.